# uWSGI vassal not spawning with correct permissions

Tags: linux, sockets, permissions, uwsgi

I have a vassal which I expect to run as the `cuckoo` user. The vassal creates a socket which Nginx can read and write to. Currently, the vassal will only spawn when the `uwsgi` users permission are applied to the socket `/var/run/cuckoo/cuckoo.sock`. The problem that occurs with when data is posted to Nginx and sent to the vassal to be written to the filesystem, the data is written with `uwsgi` instead of the `cuckoo` users permissions. Below are the respective configurations. Any thoughts on how to correctly create the vassal and its respective socket with `cuckoo` permissions so data written through the process will be written as the `cuckoo` user?

- CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009
- uwsgi-2.0.18-8.el7.x86_64
- uwsgi-plugin-common-2.0.18-8.el7.x86_64
- uwsgi-plugin-python2-2.0.18-8.el7.x86_64

*/etc/uwsgi.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
uid = uwsgi
gid = uwsgi
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
cap = setgid,setuid
```

*/etc/uwsgi.d/cuckoo.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/cuckoo/cuckoo.sock
chmod-socket = 766
plugins = python
virtualenv = /opt/cuckoo/cuckoo-virtual-env
module = cuckoo.apps.api
callable = app
uid = cuckoo
gid = cuckoo
env = CUCKOO_APP=api
env = CUCKOO_CWD=/opt/cuckoo/cuckoo-working-dir
```

Socket permissions

```
$ ls -l /var/run/cuckoo/
total 0
srwxrw-rw-. 1 uwsgi uwsgi 0 Nov  5 13:47 cuckoo.sock
$ ls -l /run/uwsgi/
total 4
srw-rw----. 1 uwsgi uwsgi 0 Nov  5 13:47 stats.sock
-rw-r--r--. 1 uwsgi uwsgi 6 Nov  5 13:47 uwsgi.pid
```

Configuration permissions

```
$ ls -l /etc/uwsgi.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 uwsgi uwsgi  117 Nov  5 13:46 /etc/uwsgi.ini

/etc/uwsgi.d:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 uwsgi uwsgi 288 Nov  5 04:22 cuckoo.ini
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are not attempting to host multiple applications, the workaround was to run `uwsgi` as the application user, in our case, the `cuckoo` user:

*/etc/uwsgi.ini*

```
[uwsgi]
uid = cuckoo
gid = cuckoo
emperor = /etc/uwsgi.d
chmod-socket = 660
emperor-tyrant = true
cap = setgid,setuid
```

and updated the configuration permissions:

```
$ ls -l /etc/uwsgi.*
-rw-r--r--. 1 cuckoo cuckoo  118 Nov  5 18:00 /etc/uwsgi.ini

/etc/uwsgi.d:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 cuckoo cuckoo 270 Nov  5 17:54 cuckoo.ini
```

This allows the vassal to correctly spawn and Nginx to access the socket.